# Adding touch option to a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a price range slider. I am following the jQuery guide and use them as reference.

My problem is that I can't add dragable behavior on the actual slider. I've researched and have tried to add `jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js`, however it did not solve my problem.

Please see below my code:

```js
  $(function() {
    $("#slider-range-min").slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 400,
      min: 400,
      max: 2000,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val("£" + ui.value);
      }
    });
    $("#amount").val("£" + $("#slider-range-min").slider("value"));
    $('#slider-range-min').draggable();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="amount">Maximum price:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>

<div id="slider-range-min"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't add dragable behavior on the actual slider"? Everything you have seem to work fine for me.

Comment: @DBS i can not drag the slider on touch devices

Comment: Is the `<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>` loading correctly? (Open your dev console and check for any errors)

Comment: Arghhh, seems that his was the answer. It was not loading correctly! Now I've used a cdn such as: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js to get the library. Can you please answer the question so I can accept it/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make sure you're correctly loading the:

```
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

Your current code expects this file to be in the same folder as your HTML page, if it's hosted elsewhere you will need to change the link or use a CDN of some form.